# Using one layout with many layout inside of it

Tags: android, layout

Hi I'm a beginner in developing android app. I just want to ask if it's a best practice to have a many layout inside one layout? Someone said that it's a bad practice so I'm a little bit curious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No,it is not a bad practice for a beginner, I will definitely advise you to experiment more and more with layouts. I myself have a major project which involves much usage of nested (layouts within layouts) layouts. Generally, relative layouts are used for using more than one layouts. Horizontal Linear layouts are used quite often within a main Vertical Linear layout. This way you can keep experimenting until you feel comfortable using them.

Answer (score 0):

It depends upon what are you trying to achieve.

If you want same activity to behave differently using condition check it is a good practice.

But trying to have more layout inside a layout file may **slow down** the app to open that specific activity (Slow rendering of the xml). Therefore creating different activity or the fragment may work well in this case.

So choice is completely your but according to the usages.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, I don't think this is a bad idea, although it might slow down your app. But it still depends on what you are doing. I don't think using a `RelativeLayout` in another `RelativeLayout` is a good idea. Because that's just not needed. One `RelativeLayout` is enough for one activity. Oh the other hand, I always nest `LinearLayout`s in `LinearLayout`s. Like this: (code is simplified)

```
<LinearLayout orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout orientation="horizontal">
        <stuff/> <stuff/> <stuff/> <stuff/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout orientation="horizontal">
        <stuff/> <stuff/> <stuff/> <stuff/>
    </LinearLayout>
<L/inearLayout>
```

The above results in a 4 x 2 rectangle of stuffs.

See? Sometimes nesting is good when you use it on `LinearLayout`s.